# Correct Dockerfile syntax for pyramid app for use with Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, dockerfile, pyramid

I want to run a pyramid app in a docker container, but I'm struggling with the correct syntax in the Dockerfile.  Pyramid doesn't have an official Dockerfile, butI found this site that recommended using an Ubuntu base image.
https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-pyramid-application

But this is for Python 2.7.  Any ideas how I can change this to 3.5?  This is what I tried:

Dockerfile
`FROM ubuntu:16.04`
`RUN apt-get update -y && \`
`apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev && \`
`pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools`
`# We copy this file first to leverage docker cache`
`COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt`
`WORKDIR /app`
`RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
`COPY . /app`
`ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]`
`CMD [ "pserve development.ini" ]`

and I run this from the command line:
`docker build -t testapp .`

but that generates a slew of errors ending with this

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/appdirs-1.4.3.dist-info/METADATA'
>   The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

And even if that did build, how will pserve execute in 3.5 instead of 2.7?  I tried modifying the Dockerfile to create a virtual environment to force execution in 3.5, but still, no luck.  For what it's worth, this works just fine on my machine with a 3.5 virtual environment.

So, can anyone help me build the proper Dockerfile so I can run this Pyramid application with Python 3.5?  I'm not married to the Ubuntu image.

Comment: If you install only Python3 in the docker image, then there is no chance the application will run in 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that can help, here's my Dockerfile for a Pyramid app that we develop using Docker. It's not running in production using Docker though.

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0
RUN echo deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    gettext \
    postgresql-client-9.5
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py develop
```

As you may notice, we use Postgres and gettext, but you can install whatever dependencies you need.

The line `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0` I think we added that because Python would buffer all outputs so nothing would be printed in the console.

And we use Python 3.5.2 for now. We tried a version a bit more recent, but we ran into issues. Maybe that's fixed now.

Also, if that can help, here's an edited version of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version : '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3.6.6-management"
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
  worker:
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    working_dir: /code
    command: command_for_worker development.ini
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  web:
    image: image_from_dockerfile
    working_dir: /code
    command: pserve development.ini --reload
    ports:
      - "6543:6543"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

We build the image by doing

```
docker build -t image_from_dockerfile .
```

Instead of passing directly the Dockerfile path in the `docker-compose.yml` config, because we use the same image for the web app and the worker, so we would have to rebuild twice every time we have to rebuild.

And one last thing, if you run locally for development like we do, you have to run

```
docker-compose run web python setup.py develop
```

one time in the console, otherwise, you'll get an error like if the app was not accessible when you `docker-compose up`. This happens because when you mount the volume with the code in it, it removes the one from the image, so the package files (like `.egg`) are "removed".

**Update**

Instead of running `docker-compose run web python setup.py develop` to generate the `.egg` locally, you can tell Docker to use the `.egg` directory from the image by including the directory in the volumes.

E.g.

```
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /code/packagename.egg-info
```

Comment: that helped a bunch, thanks!  What also helped was figuring out how to run the container interactively so I could debug, line-by-line, what was causing the problem.